# CSV File Downloaded as true.txt When Programmatically Triggered in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, amazon-s3

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with downloading .csv files programmatically in a web application. When I click on a presigned URL (pointing to an AWS S3 object) directly from the console log or navigate to it manually, the .csv file downloads correctly with the proper filename and extension. However, when I try to trigger the download programmatically using JavaScript, the file gets downloaded as true.txt instead.

Here's the frontend code snippet:

```
const DownloadData = async () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const backendUrl_fetchdata = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fetch-data/`;

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            backendUrl_fetchdata,
            {
                // request payload
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
                },
                withCredentials: true
            }
        );

        if (response.status === 200 && response.data.urls) {
            response.data.urls.forEach(({ url, filename: expectedFilename }) => {
                console.log("Downloading file from URL:", url);

                if (expectedFilename.endsWith('.csv')) {
                    // Attempt to download CSV
                    const link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.href = url;
                    link.setAttribute("download", expectedFilename);
                    document.body.appendChild(link);
                    link.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(link);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching URLs:", error);
    }
};
```

**Backend (Django):**
The backend generates presigned URLs for the files stored in AWS S3. These URLs are sent to the frontend as part of the response.

Observations:

> The console.log accurately prints the URL, and clicking it initiates
> the correct download. Manually navigating to the URL also results in
> the correct file being downloaded. When the download is triggered
> programmatically, the browser downloads a true.txt file instead.

**Questions:**

1. Why does the browser download the file as true.txt when the download is initiated programmatically, despite the URL being correct and the .csv file downloading correctly when accessed directly?
2. How can I ensure that the .csv file is downloaded with the correct filename and extension when the download is triggered programmatically?

Any insights or solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated!